# Finding the inverse function for the following function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, inverse-function

Find −1() for each function.

[image]

My answer:

[image]

**or**

[image]

The book answer:

[image]

I don't understand how the book concluded with this answer?

Comment: Why do you think either of the equations you wrote should hold?

Comment: What do you get when you write $y = {x \over x + 2}$ and take a reciprocal? What happens when you gather the terms that are a function of $x$ ($x$ can be in numerator or denominator) to one side and the others to the other side of the equation and start simplifying?

Comment: I'm not understanding the questions above. Based on what I read in the book, I have to solve for x to get the inverse function. This is a 9-week pre-calculus course. I've not taken a math class in 25 years so it's a bit dense at this speed. I need help with how it's done correctly so I can review the steps and see where I went wrong. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not clear on how you got the first line in your answer,

$$x=y \dfrac{x}{x+2}$$

but it shows some flaw in your understanding of inverses.

In an inverse function, the dependent and independent variables (i.e. $x$ and $y$) switch roles. This means that to find an inverse algebraically, the first step is to replace **each** $y$ with an $x$ and **each** $x$ with a $y$. Thus your first line should be

$$x=\dfrac{y}{y+2}$$

Then, assuming the equation is not too complex, one solves for y. You should try this for yourself first, but I've included the solution below in case you run into trouble.

> $$x=\dfrac{y}{y+2}$$
> $$x(y+2)=y$$
> $$xy+2x=y$$
> $$xy-y=-2x$$
> $$y(x-1)=-2x$$
> $$y=\dfrac{-2x}{x-1}$$

Comment: That is what I wasn't understanding. The switch of x and y variables. Math books, in my opinion, aren't explanatory at least not enough. If the math book had only explained it as clearly as "In an inverse function, the dependent and independent variables (i.e.  and ) switch roles. This means that to find an inverse algebraically, the first step is to replace each  with an  and each  with a ." I think if most math books explained concept this clearly it wouldn't be such a challenge. Thank you for this!